# Optimization of group by order by

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have the following sql query

```
SELECT a.player_id, COUNT( a.player_id ) AS views, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.link_id
FROM buyout_calculator_query AS a
LEFT JOIN player AS b ON ( a.player_id = b.player_id ) 
WHERE a.timestamp >259200
GROUP BY player_id
ORDER BY views DESC
```

and I have the following index, which is based off of various stack answers I have seen:

```
CREATE INDEX timestamp_playerid_index ON buyout_calculator_query(
timestamp,
player_id
)
```

My incorrect understanding is that this would prevent a temporary table, since timestamp is the constraint, grouped by player_id, and summed by player_id

However, when running explain, this is what I see (temp table):

```
Possible Keys: timestamp_playerid_index
Key: timestamp_playerid_index
Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

How do I optimize this query and prevent the use of temporary tables?

Comment: "How do I optimize this query and prevent the use of temporary tables?" - What if the fastest way is using a temp table?

Comment: @MitchWheat well if that is the case then I'm misguided in my question

Comment: @MitchWheat - I would suggest that the _only way_ is to use tmp tables.  (See my answer.)

Comment: ""Prevent the use of temp tables" and "Prevent 'filesort'". Neither of these is the real goal. The real goal is a faster query." - Exactly what I was hinting to poster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer is rather long winded, but I hope you will learn several things.  And I give you two *possible* improvements.

"Prevent the use of temp tables" and "Prevent 'filesort'".  Neither of these is the real goal.  The real goal is a faster query.

```
GROUP BY one_thing
ORDER BY something_else
```

will *always* (I think) need at least one temp and filesort, sometimes two.  It is simply necessary to achieve your goal.

On the flip side, a temp+filesort needed to support a `SELECT` is not necessarily a disk-based "file".  It is often merely an in-memory set of data (actually a `MEMORY` table).

Let's look further at what you have:

```
Filter on a.timestamp -- but a "range"
GROUP BY a.player_id
ORDER BY an aggregate -- not know up front, so no way to use an index.
```

*If* the optimizer does things in the order given, it could

1. use an index starting with timestamp for filtering, and write that to a tmp table
2. sort to do the `GROUP BY`
3. sort again to do the `ORDER BY`.

(I may be pessimistic about how the `GROUP BY` processing is done.  Use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` to get more insight.)

You suggested a composite `INDEX(timestamp, player_id)`.  Well, that won't be useful since the *first* part is used in a *range*.  Think of this:  You have a long list of people and their birth-years.  And you want all those with last name starting with 'B' and you want to group them by birth year.  What would be the optimal way to arrange the list so you are not copying things over and sorting them?  Then add on sorting by the most common birth year.

Back to the composite index.  As a general rule, if you are using the *first* column in the index in a 'range' context, the rest of the index goes unused.

So, the most useful index for the given query is merely `INDEX(timestamp)`.  *Correction*:  `INDEX(timestamp, player_id)` is better because it is a "covering index", hence avoids reaching into the data.  `EXPLAIN` gives you the clue with `Using index`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; I am having to guess from here out...

I guess that `player` has `PRIMARY KEY(player_id)`, correct?

You are using `LEFT` because buyout queries reference non-existent players?  Seems unlikely, so I will guess that you added `LEFT` for no valid reason.

Also, I'll guess you said `COUNT(a.player_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)` for no valid reason.

Once you get rid of the `LEFT`, we can try another formulation of the query:

```
SELECT  b.player_id, 
      ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  buyout_calculator_query
            WHERE  player_id = b.player_id
              AND  timestamp >259200 
      ) AS views,
      b.firstname, b.lastname, b.link_id
    FROM  player AS b
    ORDER BY  views DESC
```

See if that runs faster.  It has a "correlated subquery" but avoids the `GROUP BY`.  Please add this to `buyout_calculator_query`:  `INDEX(player_id, timestamp)`.

Going a step further, this may (or may not) be better:

```
SELECT  b.player_id, a.views, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.link_id
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  player_id, COUNT(*) AS views
            FROM  buyout_calculator_query
            WHERE  timestamp >259200
            GROUP BY  player_id 
      ) AS a
    JOIN  player AS b USING(player_id)
    ORDER BY  a.views DESC
```

This will be "Using index" if you have `INDEX(player_id, timestamp)`; that is an extra boost by avoiding bouncing between the index and the data.  Plus the subquery need no tmp table, nor filesort.  But the subquery generates a tmp table, and the `ORDER BY` will need a sort.